# How to turn the following string chain into string interpolation?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to turn this:

```
api.viewerUrl + (utils.includes(api.historyModeServers, api.env) ? '/' : '/#!/') + buildingId
```

Into string interpolation? (Using `${}`).

Comment: Are you using ES6?

Comment: @TrishantPahwa Yes.

Comment: You can also check out the docs on [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove '+' and wrap expressions with `${}`. Ternary operator is expression as well.

```
`${api.viewerUrl}${utils.includes(api.historyModeServers, api.env) ? '/' : '/#!/'}${buildingId}`
```

Answer (score 1):

separate conditional expression would be good practice.
easier to read and maintain.

```js
let words = (utils.includes(api.historyModeServers, api.env) ? '/' : '/#!/');
let str = `${api.viewerUrl}${words}${buildingId}`;
```